# Failed validation redirects to normal path

Tags: path-aliases

I'm using the [sub-pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module.

I can edit *node 1* of type *list* from the path *list/1/edit*. However, when validation fails I'm redirected back to *node/1/edit* (the normal path).

Is this a known limitation of the module? Something I have to accept?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module add below code,It check If url not in alias path, redirect it to aliased path.

```
function mymodule_init() {
    if(module_exists('subpathauto'){
  $alias = subpathauto_lookup_subpath('alias', current_path(), current_path());
  if (!empty($alias) && $alias != request_path()) {
    drupal_goto($alias, array(), 301);
  }
 }
}
```